# Shutil.copy2() Operation not permitted error

Tags: python, shutil

I have created the basic script below that scans a directory for wav files and copies them into a nested directory based on file attributes.

```
"""
Script that copies data from Peersonic RPA3 into directory
using file name, date and time
"""

import datetime as dt
import os
import shutil
import time
from pathlib import Path


# Function to check if survey is dusk or dawn
def duskdawn(file):
    filetime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file))
    if file_time.time() > dt.time(12):
        return "Dusk"
    else:
        return "Dawn"


def file_date(file):
    return time.strftime('%d.%m.%Y', time.localtime(os.path.getmtime(file)))


def client(file):
    return file.name[0:3]

client_lst = ['IES', 'DEC', 'TEP']

# Directory of files
path = "/Volumes/BATrecorder/WAVFILES.DIR"
for entry in os.scandir(path):
    source = entry.path
    perm = os.stat(entry).st_mode
    client_name = (client(entry))
    if entry.name.endswith(".WAV"):
        if client_name in client_lst:
            client_name = client_name
        else:
            client_name = "unknown"
    destination = f"/Volumes/Seagate Exp/Work 2020/Bat recordings/{client_name}/{file_date(entry)}/{duskdawn(entry)}"
    Path(destination).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    shutil.copy2(source, destination)
```

Initially I used the standard `shutil.copy()` function and this worked fine. However, I need to keep the original file metadata so need to use `shutil.copy2()` instead. When I use this one I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Seagate Exp/Work 2020/file_copy.py", line 43, in <module>
    shutil.copy2(source, destination)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 258, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 218, in copystat
    lookup("chflags")(dst, st.st_flags, follow_symlinks=follow)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Volumes/Seagate Exp/Work 2020/Bat recordings/unknown/31.12.2014/Dusk/@AAA_000.WAV'
```

What is going on here that causes this issue?

Comment: It seems you don't have rights to write in the destination. You are creating the entire destination as directory then try to copy your file as the directory you just created and not as a file under this directory

May be you need something like `Path(os.path.dirname(destination)).mkdir(...)` instead

Comment: Will try this, I find it odd that it writes the initial file then returns an error